# How can I use the correct rbenv Ruby version with Emacs' shell-command?

Tags: macos, emacs, zsh

Here is my current setup:

- MacBook with Mountain Lion
- Emacs is http://emacsformacosx.com/
- rbenv with global 1.9.3-p374
- Login shell is zsh

My ~/.zprofile (I am certain that the file gets executed):

```
# Customize to your needs...
export PATH=/Users/username/.rbenv/shims:/Users/username/.nvm/v0.9.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I want to use my globally defined ruby version with `M-x shell-command` (or `M-!`). I expect `M-! ruby -v` to return `ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]` but I get `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]`.

If I run `ruby -v` in `M-x shell` the correct version is loaded. I suspect that `M-!` does not work as expected as it runs as a non interactive shell.

Is there a way to fix this, besides running something like: `M-! eval "$(rbenv init -)" && ruby -v`? This works, but I do not want to insert `eval "$(rbenv init -)" &&` infront of everything I execute.

Answer (score 4):

Your path from shell needs to be seen by Emacs, and to make that easier, use the following elisp package.

https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

You can install this through el-get or manually by dropping it in your `~/.emacs.d/lisp` directory and adding this to your `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp")
(unless (require 'exec-path-from-shell nil 'noerror)
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

The lisp file will take care of the rest.